# Why is the function not displaying a winner?

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

The game requires these functions, and it works, but it does not display a winner. I am at my wits end, as this is due tomorrow night. It was assigned to me today. I have tried all that I can, and I really have no clue what to do at all.

The game works by the computer randomly picking `1` through `3`. `1` being rock, `2` being paper and `3` being scissors. The computers choice doesn't need to be displayed in the beginning. Then the user is supposed to enter in either rock paper or scissors. After that the computer's choice is to be displayed. And a winner is selected by the basic rules of rock paper scissors. If both players have the same answer its considered a tie.

And for my grade it MUST have the functions `main()`, `get_ComputerMove()`, `get_PlayerMove()`, and `calculateWinner()`.Thanks in advance.

```
import random


def startAgain():
    randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
    computerChoice = get_ComputerMove(randomNumber)
    userChoice = get_PlayerMove()
    print('The computer chose', computerChoice )
    winner, message = calculateWinner(computerChoice,userChoice )
    if winner != 'no winner':
        print(winner,'won(',message, ')')        

def getRandomNumber():
    randomNumber = random.randint( 1, 3 )
    return randomNumber

def get_ComputerMove( randomNumber ):
    if randomNumber == 1:
        computerChoice = "rock"
    elif randomNumber == 2:
        computerChoice = "paper"
    else:
        computerChoice = "scissors"

    return computerChoice
def get_PlayerMove():
    userChoice = input("Please enter your choice")
    return userChoice

def calculateWinner( computerChoice, userChoice ):
    rockMessage = "The rock smashes the scissors"
    scissorsMessage = "Scissors cuts paper"
    paperMessage = "Paper covers the rock"
    winner = "no winner"
    message = ""
    if computerChoice == "rock" and userChoice == "scissors":
       winner = "Computer"
       message = rockMessage
    elif computerChoice == "scissors" and userChoice == "rock":
       winner = "you"
       message = rockMessage
    if computerChoice == "scissors" and userChoice == "paper":
       winner = "Computer"
       message = scissorsMessage
    elif computerChoice == "paper" and userChoice == "scissors":
       winner = "you"
       message = scissorsMessage
    if computerChoice == "paper" and userChoice == "rock":
       winner = "Computer"
       message = paperMessage
    elif computerChoice == "rock" and userChoice == "paper":
       winner = "you"
       message = paperMessage                 
    return winner, message 
def main():
    randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
    computerChoice = get_ComputerMove(randomNumber)
    userChoice = get_PlayerMove()
    print("The computer chose" , computerChoice )
    winner,message = calculateWinner( computerChoice,userChoice )
    if winner != "no winner":
        print(winner,"won(",message, ")")
    while winner == "no winner":
        print('You both chose the same thing')
        winner = startAgain()       
main()
```

Comment: It works fine actually, 
Please enter your choicepaper                                                                                                                        
The computer chose rock                                                                                                                              
you won( Paper covers the rock )

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format the body text as body text in your question and not as a header.

Comment: I just realized the problem was that whenever I entered in something, I myself added a space, and it really just messed with my program. I went back and edited the code so there's a space right after it asks for choice. so instead of showing as Please enter your choicepaper, it shows as Please enter your choice paper. And its working properly now.

Comment: Technically speaking, as written here it's actually broken if you tie with the computer twice (it will not declare a winner in that situation). `startAgain` always returns `None`, which means that your `while winner == "no winner"` clause would always be `True` after a single iteration. I upvoted Vitor's answer as it solves that problem and results in a winner always being declared (as per the original question).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **repeat** the game **until** it has a winner, **while loop** doess the trick:

```
def main():
    winner = "no winner"

    while winner == "no winner":
        randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
        computerChoice = get_ComputerMove(randomNumber)
        userChoice = get_PlayerMove()

        print("The computer chose", computerChoice)
        winner, message = calculateWinner(computerChoice, userChoice)

        if winner != "no winner":
            print(winner, "won(", message, ")")
        else:
            print('You both chose the same thing')
```